# jQuery toggle both "slide" and "fade" animations at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has a `slideToggle`, and a `fadeToggle`, but they don't play well together (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2yvd/)):

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $('span')
        .slideToggle({duration: 'slow', queue: false})
        .fadeToggle({duration: 'slow', queue: false});
});
```

How can I have `slide` and `fade` toggle *at the same time*?

Comment: .animate with he right options....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.animate()` as follows:

```
$('span').animate({
  height: "toggle",
  opacity: "toggle"
});
```

Comment: note if your elements are using `display: inline-flex`, when their height and opacity are toggled the display will be `inline-block`